# Validation for multiple objects some required some not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

i have this class

```
    public class ComponentMarks
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BuildingComponent ComponentType { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 3)]
    public int Stav { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 3)]
    public int NutnostInvestice { get; set; }
    [Range(1, 3)]
    public int OdhadVyseInvestice { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

which i use in class

```
    public ComponentMarks FasadaMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks StrechaMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks DvereOknaMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks VodaMarks { get; set; }


    public ComponentMarks PlynMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks ElektroinstalaceMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks OdpadyMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks TopeniMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks DatoveSiteMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ComponentMarks VnejsiRozvodyMarks { get; set; }

}
```

And i want o All be required except PlynMarks, but PlynMarks is always required. I now i can make int properties nullable to be not required but how can i do this only for plynmarks? I want to validate on server side.

```
   <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Plyn:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PlynMarks.Stav, new {@Value = ""})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PlynMarks.Stav)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PlynMarks.NutnostInvestice, new {@Value = ""})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PlynMarks.NutnostInvestice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PlynMarks.OdhadVyseInvestice, new { @Value = "" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PlynMarks.OdhadVyseInvestice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.PlynMarks.Note, new {@Value = ""})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "i want o All be required except PlynMarks, but PlynMarks is always required" ! What does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, it means that PlynMarks doesnt have required attribute but its required. My temporary solution is to have two classes for componentMarks one with int? and one with normal int.

Comment: Why you don't add "required" for PlynMarks ?

Comment: I think the easiest way is making PlynMarks  null able by : 'public ComponentMarks? PlynMarks { get; set; }'

Comment: When i tried this i got error: The type ComponentMarks must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter T in generic type or method Nullable<T>

Comment: try :   'public Nullable<ComponentMarks> PlynMarks { get; set; }'

Comment: This gives the same error.

Comment: So change ComponentMarks properties all nullable.

Comment: When i do that all properties will not be required. But i want all properities to be required except PlynMarks.

Comment: So you can give initial values for PlynMarks and check if PlynMarks properites values are initial values then it means it's actually null. In that case you don't need nullable properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made list of componentMarks and property for ComponentMarksNullable then in controller check if ComponentMarksNullabel has values. If it has values i add it to list and then to db. Thanks for all help.